# Blender file size grows and never shrinks

Tags: blend-files, optimization

I made a huge project, wanted to reduce file size from 1.3GB to below 1GB. Compressing did not help. I removed objects from scene. Also textures. I then realized, the file size even was the same when I delete all objects. Why?

Download of sample: https://ufile.io/0cc23

Before deleting all: 1.2GB, after: 1.1GB.
[image: File size does not shrink]

Comment: Are you sure you actually removed the object data? Do they show as having zero users before closing? Don't they have fake users set up? They may be in use elsewhere in another scene or object.

Comment: I uploaded a sample. I don't know if all is removed. It seems not. But in the outliner there is nothing to find. No objects in outliner. All deleted. Still over 200MB.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try File/External Data/Unpack All Into Files?

Comment: Yes. File > External Data > unpack all. No success. That is the file I've uploaded as sample.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your file has a large size and your scenes are apparently empty it means there are other datablocks saved in your file but not in current use in your scenes, or at least your current scene.

Try switching your *Outliner* to *Group* view and you will find plenty of group definitions you can insert into your scene, with lots of high poly objects stored in them.

[image: Groups]

Otherwise if this is not the case, go into the *Outliner* and change the view context to *Datablocks*; for Blender 2.8+ versions you can use both or *Blender File* or *Data API* display modes. There you can see a list of categories containing different data-types stored inside your file, like images, objects, groups, brushes, etc. This should give a hint at what is taking the most space inside your blend file.

[image]

After that you can also have a look at orphaned data. To see this in the *Outliner* change display mode to *Orphan Data* and see what data is unused but still saved inside your file. If any is undesirable you can purge it all using the *Purge* button up top right, or individually by right clicking the item and choosing *Delete* or *Unlink*.

[image]

To actually delete data, select the (un)desired groups in the *Outliner* under *Group* mode, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> **over the group name** (not the icon) and choose *Unlink* option.

Pre Blender 2.8, you have to save the file, quit Blender and then reopen the file again, for actual data to be gone. Save again and file size should be reduced.

For 2.8+ you can check again the *Orphan Data* in the *Outliner* and repeat the steps described above.

For you particular case, only way I figured out how to actually reduce file was to go into the *Outliner*, after unlinking all groups as described above, switch to *Blender File* mode, go into the *Mesh* category and manually select everything and erase it with <kbd>Right Click</kbd> > Delete. This reduced file size to about 5Mb

Due to the large amount it is probably easier to just select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> and deselect all other categories before erasing

Comment: With your animated images (how did you do that?) I fully understand. I was on "all objects" and I still do not understand why blender does not present it that way. Great to see the "Groups" solution. Thank you

Comment: I am still unable to reduce file size to nearly zero. I can see the items but not delete them.

Comment: I forgot to add that, to actually get rid of it you have to unlink the groups from the outliner, answer updated above.

Comment: GIFs are captured with [ScreentoGif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif)

Comment: I added an animation. Problem still not solved.

Comment: Check other types of data, like animation, game logic, text editor, previews etc. Not at my computer at the moment, will test further later

Comment: OK, only way I managed to make it was by manually deleting mesh data from the outliner. Updated answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting lighting cache. In 2.8, click on little camera icon, find "Indirect Lighting" section, in there you can click on "Delete Lighting Cache".

If you hover over "Delete Lighting Cache" it will tell you how much space the cache is using.