# How to reduce bloated file size?

Tags: blend-files, optimization

I created this large scene file: lots of objects, textures, nodes, you name it, and am currently doing a post-mortem: stripping out assets so I can re-use them in later scenes.

However I'm getting some massive discrepancies in what's left in the scene and the file size housing it. I have a skybox asset that's barely 400kB in a blend file 107MB large!

I've been through all layers and stripped out objects. I've gone through the F-Curve and dopesheet to remove animations. I've gone through the materials and texture sections and pruned out unused materials, disabled fake users, axed modifiers and constraints, removed compositor nodes and deleted particle systems but still the file size takes a while to load and reads 107MB.

What's left to take out? Anyone think of any potentially overlooked 106MB item?

Blend file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13900881/Auriantation.blend

Comment: Did you look through the "Blender File" in the outliner? Use the dropdown menu there to see it. You should see EVERYTHING in the .blend...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.78 file size grows and does never shrink](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-2-78-file-size-grows-and-does-never-shrink)

Comment: @Pycoder: Yes. Nothing but the object and its necessary attributes.

Comment: Did you try "Save and Reload" a few times?

Comment: @Pycoder: Yep. Still 107MB.

Comment: Is it possible you could post the file for us to inspect?

Comment: @gandalf3: Link added to post :)

Comment: And to clarify: This file does have nodes and objects I want to keep. I just can't seem to justify to myself that a skybox, camera, a lamp and a few nodes costs 107MB.

Comment: WAIT - Found it :) The sneaky error of truncated file names... It's the skybox UV image. The file I was trimming back used an early version of the skybox which used an uncompressed PNG. I'd swapped in a JPG file in later versions which was just as good but way cheaper on memory. I didn't pick that up because the Blender UI truncates longer file names on smaller screens :( Crap. Sorry for wasting your time guys.