# how to remove the link library in blender with blender python

Tags: python

i want to remove link library

[image]

I read this link.

[How to remove a linked library in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78809/how-to-remove-a-linked-library-in-blender)

how to do it with blender python? is there any way.