# File much larger than expected

Tags: objects, blend-files, data-blocks

I have a file that has 25 MB, but in the scene I just see a mesh with 6000 vertices. How can I find out where all those MB are coming from?

Edit: It turned out there were several textures packed. One surprisingly had a size of 23 MB. Surprisingly, because the texture unpacked didn't look like 23 MB. So, the question remains, how could I find out *FAST* where those MBs come from? Digging through materials (unpacking each) certainly wasn't fast. Using blender --debug and Memory Statistics didn't expose what I was looking for at all...

Comment: You can run Blender from command line and use memory statistics from spacebar search for one. Outliner opened in blender file view is useful also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.78 file size grows and does never shrink](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-2-78-file-size-grows-and-does-never-shrink)

Comment: No, not a duplicate at all...