# Blender file size is getting high

Tags: modifiers, unity, blend-files

I have imported assets in blender and saved it. After I have added some assets and deleted the old ones. But the file size keeps on increasing.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it is vague and devoid of any information that would allow us to diagnose your problem. Please edit it and provide more details so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are very low on detail about your problem so it's difficult to help. We don't even know the assets type you are talking about nor your Blender version.   Plus there are some topics about such problems you could have found by yourself by google-ing it. But here are some tips :

First, check out [that topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-2-78-file-size-grows-and-does-never-shrink).
Then, if you have a bunch of images, like said in the upper topic you have to go on the Outliner's Blenderfile mode, navigate to your unwanted images and **Right-Click** → **Delete** everything you want to delete. You can also use the UV/Image editor, open your unwanted images and **Shift-Click the X icon** in order to force deletion.

In order to apply all these actions, you have to save your blend file then re-open it.

If you need more, I think you can find a lot everywhere too.