# Blender file size bloated after importing mocap data

Tags: blend-files, actions, motion-capture, optimization

This is not a question, just wanted to share something that I found out recently. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

So, our mocap result generated a bunch of actions, one action per bone. And actions takes a lot of space apparently. It increases our project file size from 2MB to 500MB. (78MB after compression). Is this normal for 2 minutes of mocap data with fingers? We used Motive for this.

Comment: Thanks for the post. While answering your own question is entirely possible and even encouraged when find a solution, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts so the solution to the issue is displayed as separate answer in the proper answer section below, while keeping it distinct from the enquiry in the question section above? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: after a successful retarget animation, there should be only 1 new combined action. And that is the only thing you need. Delete all other actions. Access actions list from Outliner -> Display Mode: Blender File -> Actions. Also delete the unused armature leftover.
[image: How to delete unused actions]

Our project file size went down to 9MB uncompressed.

I found how to do it here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67665/150823