# Low Poly file is way too big

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, materials, objects

[image]I've been looking everywhere to find a solution to this, and I am desperate. I have a low poly file of an asteroid with a small material attached (just a 1K normal map and one color) and the poly count is 24 but the file is 112 mb. I managed to save similar files with about twice the poly count by appending the models and their size is about 600kb each (roughly). Appending these however is just not working and still saving them at around 112mb. I don't know what else to try. Please send help. SOS.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-file-size-grows-and-never-shrinks

Comment: Thank you, I actually looked at this before and didn't think I had any extra data (because I hadn't appended anything else) but it turned out it grabbed a bunch of files I appended from something else...long story short, this really helped. This has been a 2 hour long issue for me! I hope you have a great day!

Comment: @Bren Just a tip, when you've read that before and didn't think you had any extra data: do this first and clean up anyway, you've got nothing to lose if it's orphan data ;) Better than wasting two hours on searching for other solutions.

Comment: @Bren Hello and welcome. If an answer worked for you [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).